# Is scrolling to bottom after render a good use case for useLayoutEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Is scrolling to bottom after render a good use case for useLayoutEffect ?

For example:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const element = divRef.current;
  const { scrollHeight } = element;
  element.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
}, []);
```

Is that any different from:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const element = divRef.current;
  const { scrollHeight } = element;
  element.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
}, []);
```

**UPDATE:**

This will run on the 1st time I render my component. I don't want my users to see any flickering (i.e: I just want them to see the "already" scrolled to bottom situation). In this case, will `useLayoutEffect` allow me to achieve this behavior? By doing things synchronously before allowing the browser to re-paint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is following.

`useEffect` runs **asynchronously** **after** the render is committed to the screen.

`useLayoutEffect` on the other hand based on [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) runs:

> **synchronously** after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from
> the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside
> useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, **before the browser has
> a chance to paint.**

Because of this if you update screen in `useEffect` you may notice some blink effect sometimes. Because screen was updated then you immediately updated it again in `useEffect`.

But most of the times you probably need `useEffect`. Docs:

> Prefer the standard useEffect when possible to avoid blocking visual
> updates.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have been more clear of what I was asking.This will run on the 1st time I render my component. I don't want my users to see any flickering (i.e: I just want them to see the "already" scrolled to bottom situation). In this case, will `useLayoutEffect` allow me to achieve this behavior? By doing things synchronously before allowing the browser to re-paint?

Comment: @cbdeveloper yes, that does sound more appropriate for `useLayoutEffect`